# Why is GnuCash now tracking share prices in fractions?

Tags: gnucash, securities

Prior to the update to version 3 (ie, the 2.6 branch), all my funds were tracked with decimal values. Now, they're all fractions... and odd ones, at that.

Do I really care that shares went from trading at 45 + 5/6, then went down to 44 + 47/117, and finally traded at 46 + 4/11?

No.
No, I don't.

I want the decimal values. They mean more to me, and they're actually how I'm entering my data anyway.

Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to turn this off. Please, how do I get my sanity back?

Comment: Um yep - strange.  For what it's worth, as soon as you click to edit, the decimal value is displayed for editing.  But still, I'm yet to see a broker report prices in that format.   I'm guessing somebody went rogue on this one.  Posted to gnucash-users - if an answer is to be had, it will be had there relatively quickly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To follow up in 2019, gnucash version 3.3 and later have fixed [the bug](https://bugs.gnucash.org/show_bug.cgi?id=794755) discussed in the [other answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/96213/76120) by Geert Janssens. But you must go to **Preferences** -> **General** and select **Force Prices to display as decimals**. This will cause the prices to be rounded.

Answer (score 9):

Just noticed that in Gnucash 4.2. Awful. Annoying. Not only are the fractions hard to read, they take up twice as much space!

The preference is now Numbers, Date, Time > Force prices to display as decimal. Like Benjamin, I got my sanity back. This should be the default.

Comment: @BobBaerker This answer provides the updated location of the preference asked about.

Answer (score 6):

This is a bug:

https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=794755

Unfortunately nobody has found time to fix it yet...

Comment: Updated thread:
https://bugs.gnucash.org/show_bug.cgi?id=794755

Comment: If I read the thread right, a fix is going out in the nightlies. I'd expect it to make it to release in the next minor version or three.

Comment: @BenjaminChambers: Just today, prices started displaying as fractions for me. I had to manually choose the "force decimals" option.

Comment: 3 years later (version 4.5) and it's still there.